# level of C warning

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio warning level meanings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644011/visual-studio-warning-level-meanings)

After compiling the C code with MSVC compiler, We get list of warnings.

I see that warnings are categorised in levels of 1,2,3 and 4 as per my warning list.

My question is:

Does level of a warning signifies the severity of the warning?

If yes, which level is more severe? level 1 or level 4?

Thx

Comment: -1 for not even trying http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx:

> - Level 0 disables all warnings.
> - Level 1 displays severe warnings. Level 1 is the default setting.
> - Level 2 displays all level 1 warnings and warnings that are less severe than level 1.
> - Level 3 displays all level 2 warnings and all other warnings that are recommended for production purposes.
> - Level 4 displays all level 3 warnings and informational warnings. We recommend that you use this option only to provide lint-like warnings.
>     However, for a new project, it may be best to use /W4 in all
>     compilations; this will ensure the fewest possible hard-to-find code
>     defects.

Comment: purpose is to port 32 bit project to 64 bit project, so /W4 is ok?

Comment: and this project is network protocol related code