# gcc -Wall -pedantic -Wextra in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

On linux I have used these flags to compile with gcc

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -g -Wextra -pthread
```

What are my options in VS to enable similar flags? Extra warnings, etc.

Comment: Have you seen https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx?

Comment: Probably you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644011/visual-studio-warning-level-meanings)

Comment: @NathanOliver no I have not, just https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx thanks

Comment: @smkanadl thats applicable to c++ as well?

Comment: @rluks Not exactly, but the general intention should be the same in C# and C++.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `/Yd` for enabling the placement of complete debugging information in all object files and `/Wall` for enabling all warnings, including warnings that are disabled by default.

More options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx

How to set them in case you don't know: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c553zwz0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The `/Yd` option is deprecated and should now be replace by `/Zi`

Answer (score 2):

As said on this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa.aspx) :

> You can set compiler options for each project in its Property Pages dialog box. In the left pane, select Configuration Properties, C/C++ and then choose the compiler option category. The topic for each compiler option describes how it can be set and where it is found in the development environment. See Compiler Options for a complete list."

[Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx)