# Qt Creator Error For Wextra is not Working

Tags: c++, qt

:-1: error: D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall  -Wextra -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector
not working wextra

Answer (score 0):

***D8021*** suggests you are using **MSVC**, but you are providing command line switches for **gcc**...

MSVC does not have a command line switch named /Wextra, just /Wall

A quick search even here on SO would have answered your question:

1. [cmake invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274006/cmake-invalid-numeric-argument-wextra)
2. [gcc -Wall -pedantic -Wextra in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948142/gcc-wall-pedantic-wextra-in-visual-studio).

Comment: still its not working in QT creator i am new in this can you give me another solution for this

Comment: cmake invalid numeric argument '/Wextra' i check this link they are saying like we have to add some code in CMakelist.txt file . this file where i can get in C:/Qt/ directory?. or in my project i have to make something like this File?