# Windows - Visual Studio 2019 - cmake - cl.exe broken

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I have Visual Studio 2019, latest build.

If I open cmd or Visual Studio developer cmd and run `cmake ../` from `build_win` directory I got this output:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29914.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: F:/Project/build_win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_72b6d.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine verze 16.9.0+5e4b48a27 pro .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Všechna práva vyhrazena.

      Optimalizující kompilátor C/C++ společnosti Microsoft (R) verze 19.28.29914 pro procesory x64
      cl /c /Zi /Wall /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++17 /Fo"cmTC_72b6d.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_72b6d.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  -Wextra -O3 F:\Project\build_win\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    cl : command line error D8021: argument /Wextra [F:\Project\build_win\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_72b6d.vcxproj]


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/Project/build_win/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "F:/Project/build_win/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

My CMakeLists.txt is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(TORCH_DIR "f:/Project/libtorch")
message("Torch: ${TORCH_DIR}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -O3")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

project(TorchDemo)

add_definitions(/FI"stdint.h")
   
set(PROJECT_ROOT "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(VSRC "${PROJECT_ROOT}/Torch") 

include_directories(${VSRC}/)                                  

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${TORCH_DIR})

find_package(Torch CONFIG REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

message("Torch libraries: ${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(torch_demo ${VSRC}/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(torch_demo "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET torch_demo
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:torch_demo>)
endif (MSVC)
```

Any ideas what is wrong? If I run `cl.exe` directly, it runs.

Comment: The error message is about `-Wextra` compiler flag, which is for gcc/clang and which is not supported by MCVC (`cl` compiler). If you are looking for MSVC alternatives for this option, see other questions. E.g. that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948142/gcc-wall-pedantic-wextra-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you, solved the error. Could you post it as answer, please?