# Getting too many outputs when using <, <=, >= operators

Tags: c#

I've been working on a program for a fish daycare. The idea is that the customer enters their information (name, fishes name, fishes species, and length of fish in inches) and depending on what they enter in inches, returns their information and their fee at the end. I have it all written out and it does what I want except when ever it gets to the fee it outputs more than what it should.

For Example: if the user enters their fishes length to be 21, instead of it outputting the "Fee: 16$" it'll output both "Fee: 12$" and "Fee: 16$".

I know it has something to do with how I set up my operators (<, >, <=, >=) and that's why it's outputting more than what I want, I just can't put my finger on how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
namespace Fish_O_Rama
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaring constants for fish sizes
            const int FishSizeSmall = 9;
            const int FishSizeMed1 = 10;
            const int FishSizeMed2 = 20;
            const int FishSizeBig1 = 21;
            const int FishSizeBig2 = 30;
            const int FishSizeBiggest = 31;

            //Declaring constants for the fees
            const string FishMonSmall = ("Fee: 7$");
            const string FishMonMed = ("Fee: 12$");
            const string FishMonBig = ("Fee: 16$");
            const string FishMonBiggest = ("Fee: 20$");

            //Accepting input from the customer
            Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
            string CustName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter your fishes name: ");
            string FishName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter your fishes species: ");
            string FishSpecies = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter the length of your fish in inches: ");
            string FishLength = Console.ReadLine();

            //Outputting the users input
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + CustName);
            Console.WriteLine("Fishes Name: " + FishName);
            Console.WriteLine("Species: " + FishSpecies);

            //Fish under 10 inches
            if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) < FishSizeSmall)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(FishMonSmall); 
            }

            //Fish 10 inches to 20 inches
            if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) >= FishSizeMed1 || Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) <= FishSizeMed2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(FishMonMed);
            }

            //Fish greater than 20 inches but up to 30 inches
            if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) >= FishSizeBig1 || Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) <= FishSizeBig2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(FishMonBig);
            }

            //Fish greater than 30 inches
            if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) > FishSizeBiggest)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(FishMonBiggest);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `else` may be?? Also, `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Learning to [use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will be invaluable.

Comment: @DourHighArch: I'm using Visual Studios, does it come default with all the compiler warnings turned on? I'm a novice so I apologize if I'm asking something obvious.

Comment: You can see what compiler warnings you have turned on [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644011/). I suggest reading a [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx).

Comment: @DourHighArch Will give it a good read. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a Fish can only have 1 length, it might make sense to use "if/else if" statements rather than a series of "if" statements. That way, it will short-circuit when the condition in the "if/else if" evaluates to `true` rather than potentially testing additional unnecessary cases after the correct case has been identified. In the case of a length of 21,

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) >= FishSizeMed1 || Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) <= FishSizeMed2)
```

evaluates to `true` because you are using `||` rather than `&&`. I believe you are trying to determine if the length is between two values, and not greater than or equal to a minimum value **or** less than or equal to a maximum value. Since 21 is greater than 10, the value of `FishSizeMed1`, the condition after `||` does not even need to be checked. This is because because `true` || `true` and `true` || `false` both evaluate to `true`.

The next `if`:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) >= FishSizeBig1 || Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) <= FishSizeBig2)
```

also evaluates to `true` for the same reason as above: 10 is greater than or equal to 21, the value of `FishSizeBig1`.

Understanding the difference between the two AND and OR Boolean expressions will fix this, and chaining with "if/else if" statements will make the application more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the logical or statement "||" wen I should have been using logical and statements "&&".

Like so:

```
//Fish 10 inches to 20 inches
        if (Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) >= FishSizeMed1 && Convert.ToInt32(FishLength) <= FishSizeMed2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(FishMonMed);
        }
```

Thanks Gusman.